# Spring boot failed to start

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a error and I tried to figure out what was wrong for 2 hours and I can't fix it.

I ran my spring boot app using `java -jar` command, it's a package and it couldn't start.

I set the properties file to set the port for 80 and my `firewalld` is disabled and I ran on Centos7 machine. and I tried `netstat` command and there was no service for port 80 so it is not a port problem i think.

This is the errlog:

...

```
2019-01-21 16:02:56.183  INFO 8158 --- [           main] com.springboot.PjsSpringBootApplication  : Starting PjsSpringBootApplication v1.0 on carpfishncptest1 with PID 8158 (/home/jh31/pjs-spring-boot/target/pjs-spring-boot-1.0.jar started by jh31 in /home/jh31/pjs-spring-boot/target)
2019-01-21 16:02:56.186  INFO 8158 --- [           main] com.springboot.PjsSpringBootApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-01-21 16:02:57.702  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 80 (http)
2019-01-21 16:02:57.729  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-01-21 16:02:57.730  INFO 8158 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.14]
2019-01-21 16:02:57.740  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2019-01-21 16:02:57.812  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-01-21 16:02:57.813  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1571 ms
2019-01-21 16:02:58.056  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-01-21 16:02:58.174  WARN 8158 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.m.MustacheAutoConfiguration      : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Mustache configuration, or set spring.mustache.check-template-location=false)
2019-01-21 16:02:58.192  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
2019-01-21 16:02:58.277 ERROR 8158 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase   : Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1004) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:226) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:259) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) [spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at com.springboot.PjsSpringBootApplication.main(PjsSpringBootApplication.java:10) [classes!/:1.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [pjs-spring-boot-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [pjs-spring-boot-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [pjs-spring-boot-1.0.jar:1.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [pjs-spring-boot-1.0.jar:1.0]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:236) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1085) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:568) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1001) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar!/:9.0.14]
        ... 22 common frames omitted

2019-01-21 16:02:58.282  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-01-21 16:02:58.292  INFO 8158 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-01-21 16:02:58.293 ERROR 8158 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 80 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 80, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2019-01-21 16:02:58.296  INFO 8158 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

...

Comment: `java.net.SocketException: Permission denied` -> https://askubuntu.com/q/159609/707903 (what is your system/environment?)

Comment: I believe that on Linux you seed to be a 'sudo'er to use port 80. Either run as superuser or use 8080.

Comment: @xerx593 yes so after this I tried with sudo, thank you but unfortunately, it was not a single problem

Comment: Does it work if you try port 8080?  Also, check netstat -a to see if something is already using port 80.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log says everything.

> The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 80 failed to start.
>   The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

That port is currently used, you might have other server using this port at the moment (another run/debug maybe?). Anyways, for development reasons I'd suggest to use different port at all.

In `application.properties` put `server.port=8080` or something like that - smaller chance it's used by an other process.

Comment: I suppose spring-boot set its server port 8080 as a default. so I changed it to 80 with that method and it wasn't work but somehow it was solved, because I used embeded tomcat and its setting use servlet version 3.0 not 2.5 so i added dependency in my pom.xml and it fixed. thank you tho!